# Finding files by names

Tags: dired

How can I bring all files with names that conform a specific regex, recursively in a directory tree, to a single dired buffer?

So I can rename/delete them all at once?

Comment: Have you considered `find-name-dired' already? (Uses wildcard, not regexps.)

Comment: You should submit that as an answer @MarcoWahl . I had no idea dired could do that!

Comment: Library [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el) gives you an enhanced version of command `find-name-dired`. It accepts optional args that specify (1) min & max search depths and (2) paths to exclude from searching.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Wildcard

Use

```
M-x find-name-dired
```

to get files according to a wildcard.

#### Example

Find all files with suffix "org" in directory "~/org/".  Enter the following

```
M-x find-name-dired
~/org
*org
```

and enjoy.

## Regular Expression

Use

```
M-x find-dired
```

with suitable arguments to get files according to a regular expression.

#### Example

Find all files with suffix "org" in directory "~/org/".  Enter the following

```
M-x find-dired
~/org
-regex ".*org$"
```

and enjoy.

Comment: Is it possible to automatize this process where automatically check for `*org` without manually entering it

Comment: If I understand you correctly there are many possibilities.  E.g. make a special seach a command with (defun my-find-orgfiles () (interactive) (find-name-dired "~/myorgs/" "*org")) and put it into your init file. Then use M-x my-find-orgfiles RET.  Or even bind the command to a key.

Comment: Can `my-find-orgfiles ()` followed by "t" and "Q" // that selects all and apply? @Marco Wahl

Answer (score 5):

## Regular Expression

To use a regex, you might also try `find-lisp-find-dired`.
This command belongs to the standard lib. **find-lisp**, which is entirely
written in elisp i.e., you don't need to have installed an external
`find` program.

For instance, the following shows all the files with
extension '.el' under the directory ~/lisp:

```
M-x find-lisp-find-dired RET ~/lisp RET \.el\' RET
```

(The match honors `case-fold-search`).

## Wildcard

It's worth to note that since the next Emacs release (v26.1) Dired
supports wilcards in the directory part of the file name argument.
That means the following works:

```
C-x d ~/soft/*/*.c RET
```

(The match is case-sensitive).

This command shows in a Dired buffer all the files with extension
'.c', 2 depth levels under *'~/soft'*.  That means, all files like
*'~/soft/foo/bar.c'* will be listed, but not files like *'~/soft/qux.c'*
nor *'~/soft/foo/baz/qux.c'*.

The same but case-insensitive:

```
C-x d ~/soft/*/*.[cC] RET
```

### Bonus

If you are running Dired with a 'ls' implemented in elisp,
'ls-lisp' or 'eshell-ls', then you can **recursively** list all the files
matching a wildcard with the following syntaxis:

```
C-x d ~/soft/**/*.c RET
```

Note the '**'.  In this case all files under *'~/soft'* matching the
wildcard are shown, even *'~/soft/qux.c'*.

However, when you are using `insert-directory-program`
the wildcard expansion is made by the system shell; that means,
this recursive '**' syntaxis just works if it's supported by your shell.
For instance zsh does support it, but bash doesn't.  With shells other
that zsh the previous command will do the same as:

```
C-x d ~/soft/*/*.c RET
```